# Object method approach to .setLeftParens .setRightParens & .setOr in SuiteScript 2.X

Tags: suitescript2.0

I'm searching for the equivalent in SS 2.X of this:

```
new nlobjSearchFilter('postingperiod', 'transaction', 'is', period).setLeftParens(1).setOr(true)
```

This seems to not work:

```
searchMod.createFilter({
                        name: 'postingperiod',
                        operator: searchMod.Operator.IS,
                        join: 'transaction',
                        values: period
                    }).setLeftParens(1).setOr(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter expressions (`Search.filterExpression`) to group filters using `and` or `or`.

The sample below is from the Help Center:

```
search.create({
    type: search.Type.CUSTOMER,
    filters: [
        ['email', search.Operator.STARTSWITH, 'kwolff'],
        'and',
        [
            ['id', search.Operator.EQUALTO, 107], 'or',
            ['id',  search.Operator.EQUALTO, 2508]
        ]
    ]
});
```